# Detect upper and lower case in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    printf("Hello World ! Right something you want to know about\n");`

    scanf_s("%c", &c);

    if (c = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z') 
    {
        printf("\nThe input is an upper case letter\n");
    }
    else if  (c = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z') 
    {
        printf("\nThe input is lower case letter\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am very new to C programming, and I was trying to make a program that detects upper case and lower case letters, but this doesn't work and obviously I can't figure out why!

Comment: don't use commas in your if statements, use `||` which is OR

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &c);` --> `scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);`

Comment: Wow, there are (unintentionally) quite a few C language features here that are seldom used. The first thing to do when you make a new C project is to amp up the warnings. They really help point out some questionable usage and "[undefined behavior](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)". Look for [`-Wall` and `-Wextra`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) or equivalents in your compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several problems:

1. You use `=` instead of `==`. This will *assign* to the variable, rather than test it.
2. As the commenter pointed out, you cannot use commas like this; you need to use the `OR` operator (`||`).
3. This is way more complicated than it needs to be, considering that `A-Z` and `a-z` are both in consecutive ranges. You can just `if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')`.
4. The whole program is unnecessary, since there are already the functions `islower()` and `isupper()` in `ctype.h` that do this for you.

Comment: The `is....()`  is a good way to go, yet this answer does not explain/demo their proper use.  Note, `if (isupper(c)) ...` cam be UB when `c < 0`.

Comment: "considering that A-Z and a-z are both in consecutive ranges." is a very common implementation, yet no specified by C.

Comment: @chux `A-Z` are `0x41-0x5a` in ASCII, UTF-8, ISO Latin 1, ISO Latin 2, Windows-1252, MacRoman, Shift-JIS, and every other meaningful 8-bit string encoding that I can think of that could be reasonably expected to be in use nowadays. Even before the world standardized on UTF-8, that wasn't likely ever to change, since it would break a million things if it did. Nowadays, of course, we *have* standardized on Unicode—in C11, there's even support for UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 string literals—so the question is pretty much settled. We can be secure that `A-Z` and `a-z` are ranges.

Comment: Code C to common practice or code to the C spec - your choice.

Comment: @chux Given that the world has standardized on Unicode for the representation of string data, UTF-8 *is* the spec for single-byte encodings.

Answer (score 2):

This is a much easier way to do what you wanted:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
   char c;

   printf("Enter The Character : ");
   scanf(" %c", &c);

   if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
   {
      printf("Character is Upper Case Letters");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Character is Not Upper Case Letters");
   }
   return (0);
}
```

The mistakes in your code are the exact ones Charles Srstka mentioned, and your code is way too messy

Comment: No, this is not strictly correct.  Only the digit representations `'0'-'9'` are guaranteed to be represented consecutively.  As the comments say, use the standard `isupper()` and `islower()` functions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I didn't use the built in functions simply because maybe the OP needs to "create" his own way to do it for school or something like that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle How do you figure? `'A'-'Z'` are `0x41-0x5a` in ASCII, and pretty much every relevant single-byte character set that you're likely to run into in modern times is compatible with ASCII in the low range. I don't think OP is going to be processing data in EBCDIC (and even if they are, comparing against `'A'`, `'B'`, etc. are just going to compare against the ASCII values anyway).

Comment: @IgorPavkovic Which is why we should just explain what they did wrong instead of doing the whole assignment for them ;-)

Comment: @CharlesSrstka oh yeah, sometimes I just tend to do the whole thing and kinda regret it afterwards...But sometimes showing someone how its done is better than explaining him step by step, at least I've had some of those cases

Comment: I wonder if any of the methods suggested would recognize that Σ, for example, is upper-case? I appreciate that this is an educational exercise, but it worries me a little that new programmers continue to be taught that a `char` can meaningfully hold a letter.